# Rails 5: Add record to join table without model (has_and_belongs_to_many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a `User` and `MeetOption` table. This is a many-to-many relationship, and I was able to create a join table using the create_join_table command:

`rails g migration CreateJoinTableUsersMeetOptions users meet_options`

This generated a migration file:

```
class CreateJoinTableUsersMeetOptions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :users, :meet_options do |t|
      # t.index [:user_id, :meet_option_id]
      # t.index [:meet_option_id, :user_id]
    end
  end
end
```

I also created the association between user and meet_option models using `has_and_belongs_to_many`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :meet_options
#More codes below
end
```

---

```
class MeetOption < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

The association works fine, and I can query for example, `user.meet_options` in Rails console.

My question is: there is no model for the joined `MeetOptionsUsers` table, so how can I add records to it? Right now, I have to manually add rows, i.e. `user_id = 1; meet_option_id = 2`, using a GUI database software (Postico).

Is there a way to add records such as `MeetOptionUser.create(user_id: 1, meet_option_id: 2)` in Rails console, just like when there's an ActiveRecord model associated with it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, you should be able to use normal Active Record association methods to link your `Users` and `MeetOptions` together.  You should not need to manipulate the join table directly.  Rails takes care of that for you.  The [Ruby on Rails Guide has_and_belongs_to_many Association Reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference) lists all of the useful methods automatically created by this association.

Here are some methods you may find useful.

The `collection<<(object,..)` will add one or more objects to the join table.  For example:

```
@user.meet_options << @meet_option
```

The above will associate provided `@meet_option` record with `@user` by adding  the appropriate entry in the join table.  In this case, a record with `user_id: @user.id` and `meet_option_id: @meet_option.id` will be added to the join table.  The reverse accomplishes the same thing:

```
@meet_option.users << @user
```

Another useful method is `collection.delete(object,...)`.  This allows you to remove associations from the join table.  It does not delete the associated objects.  For example:

```
@user.meet_options.delete @meet_option
```

The above will remove the association between `@user` and `@meet_option` by deleting the appropriate record from the join table.  However, it does not delete `@user` from the `users` table, nor does it delete `@meet_option` from the `meet_options` table.

`collection.destroy(object,...)` does pretty much the same thing as `collection.delete(object,...)`.

`collection=(objects)` will make the collection contain only the supplied objects by adding or deleting from the join table as required.

There are many other using methods in this association.  I recommend reviewing the linked [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference).  Using these methods, you should be able to manage the join table without manipulating it directly.  Let Rails and Active Record do the work for you.

**Final Thought**

If you want to have more direct access to the join table via a join model, the you should not use the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association.  Perhaps you want to add more attributes to your join table or you want to have validations or callbacks on the join model itself. In this case, you should use a [has_many :through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) instead. [This blog post](http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/) walks through how to set that up.

Comment: Excellent answer. I was able to use the shovel operator `<<` you mentioned to add records to the join table.
`option = MeetOption.find_by(name: 'Mentorship')`

`user.meet_options << option`

It also works with multiple meet_option items as well

`options = MeetOption.all`

`user.meet_options << options`

Comment: I have many uses of `has_many :through` throughout the project, but this time I figure I just need a simple many-to-many relationship, and the join table will not hold any other attributes. Good thoughts, thank you.

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help.